# How to create a Path from a variable?

Tags: python

I have been running some script in VBA which I like to convert in Python. In VBA I use variables to identify the path from which the raw data are collected so that the same script can be used in any machine. In order to do do so in VBA I identify the path by using the using the following string:

```
"C:\Users\" & Environ$("username") & "\Data"
```

Is there a way I can identify in the same way the path in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to add to Matthias answer: in case you are looking to use python to "find" a path to the save a file you should keep in mind that despite printing the correct path, Python won't recognize the path unless, after identify the correct Path, you convert it to a string

i.e.: suppose you set your path as a variable

```
path =  pathlib.Path(__file__).parent / 'subfolder' / 'datafile.csv'
```

then you need to covert path as a string to be used to open/save a file

```
path1 = str(path)
```

then you can use path1 to open/save a file

Comment: Using a path with [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) works for me without doing a conversion to string. `open` doesn't expect a string but a [path-like](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-path-like-object) object as the first-parameter and an instance of `pathlib.Path` is one of those.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) from the Python Standard Library.

```
import pathlib
print(pathlib.Path.home() / 'Data')
```

In older versions of Python (before `pathlib`) you could use [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html).

```
import os.path
print(os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'Data'))
```

---

Some additional info: if you want to reference the path where your script is, you can do that too. You just have to know that `__file__` contains the full path to your script.

```
import pathlib

# full path to the script
print(pathlib.Path(__file__))

# full path to the scripts folder
print(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent)

# full path to the subfolder 'subfolder' in the scripts folder
print(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent / 'subfolder')

# full path to a file in the subfolder
print(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent / 'subfolder' / 'datafile.csv')
```

Comment: Thanks Matthias! Really appreciate your help